# Best practice for Vue Typescript Component class property initializers

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am seeing a lot of conflicting documentation about Vue + Typescript component classes.

Where does one define properties? In the `@Component` annotation as outlined [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)? As `@Prop` annotated instance properties as outlined [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)?

Where does one initialized defined properties? In the constructor? In the field-level property definition?

Is there a definitive, up-to-date reference for these things, or an up-to-date sample app?

Here's what I have now:

```
<template>
    <div class='contacts'>

        <b-form @submit="search">
            <b-form-group>
                <b-form-input v-model="q"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>

            <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Search</b-button>
        </b-form>

        <b-table :items='contacts'></b-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator'

    @Component
    export default class Contacts extends Vue {
        constructor(options: any) {
            super(options);
            this.q = 'dummy data';
            this.contacts = [{
                'id': 1,
                'first_name': 'Lukas',
                'last_name': 'Stigers',
                'email': null,
                'gender': 'Male',
                'phone': '776-878-7222'
            }, {
                'id': 2,
                'first_name': 'Dari',
                'last_name': 'Matkin',
                'email': null,
                'gender': 'Female',
                'phone': '833-146-3305'
            }]
        }

        @Prop() private q: string

        @Prop() private contacts: any

        search(event:Event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('You searched for ' + this.q)
        }
    }

</script>
```

This works, but I'm receiving these warnings in the browser:

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "q"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it appears that you are using `vue-property-decorator` and not `vue-class-component`. You can find the github page for `vue-property-decorator` [here](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator).

Second, You're getting that error because you're declaring a prop using `@Prop()` but you're then setting its value in the constructor. If you want a default value for your prop add it to the decorator like this

```
@Prop({ default: 'dummy data'})
private q: string;
```

if you want `q` to be part of the components data just define it as a property on the class without the decorator like

```
private q: string = 'dummy data';
```

Comment: The `HelloWorld.vue` in the Vue new project template used `vue-property-decorator`. Is `vue-class-component` an alternate/better option?

Comment: `vue-class-component` just gives you the `@Component` decorator and it recommends `vue-property-decorator` for other decorators like `@Watch` and `@Prop`. `vue-property-decorator` actually depends on `vue-class-component` so if you import `component` from `vue-property-decorator` you're actually using `vue-class-component`. `vue-property-decorator` just gives you more decorators to work with than just the `@Component` class decorator. At least that is my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `default` argument of the `@Prop` decorator:

```
@Prop({
  default: 'dummy data'
}) private q!: string
```

Comment: Thanks. Any link to preferred documentation? I needed to use a function for the default contacts array, and it appears to be happy.

Comment: @SamBarnum You can find [the documentation](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) here.

Comment: What's that ! for?
private q!

Comment: @Julia `private` indicates the member access type. The `!` tells typescript that this property is initialized **without** a value. And the `: string` tells typescript that this variable will **always** be a string (once initialized)